# Access MySQL server from Objective-C project with ARC

Tags: mysql, objective-c, xcode, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I can't seem to find a solution to access a MySQL server from an Objective-C Mac OS project (which uses ARC).

I tried to use the MySQL [framework that Sequel Pro provides](http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Source_Code), but that crashes (EXC_i386_GPFLT) my App whenever I just create a connection object:

```
SPMySQLConnection *conn = [[SPMySQLConnection alloc] init];
```

I don't know whether that is a bug in the framework or if I need to do something else in order to use it.

I tried a few other libraries (like [MySqueakQl](https://github.com/ciaranj/MySqueakQl)) but none of them are ARC compatible.

Also I tried to link to `libmysqlclient.a` directly, but if I copy that library into my project, I get a code signing error; if I just link to the .a in `/usr/local/mysql/lib/`, I get another error: `dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib ... Reason: image not found`. I have to admit that I have zero experince with using third-party libraries (whether .a or .dylib) and probably didn't do it right.

I'm a bit surprised that there doesn't seem to be an up-to-date (read: working) solution out there. I know, consumer apps rather use Core Data, but I have to access out company database server.

Has anybody seen a solution (libary?) that works more or less "out of the box"? I'd be willing to pay for something that actually works.

A good **tutorial on how to use .a libraries** in Xcode projects that would also help me to understand where the dylib error comes from would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I probably made some mistake when including the library.

The right steps to do this:

- Drag the `libmysqlclient.a` library into your project window
- Make sure you set *Copy items if needed* to **Yes**, and that it is added to your main target
- Drag a folder containing the headers (found under `/usr/local/mysql/include`) into your project window
- Again, make sure you set *Copy items if needed* to **Yes** and the correct target is checked.

Then:

```
#import "mysql.h"
- (BOOL) mySQLTest {
    MYSQL connection;
    mysql_init(&connection);
    if(!mysql_real_connect(&connection,
                           [self.host UTF8String],
                           [self.user UTF8String],
                           [self.password UTF8String],
                           [self.database UTF8String],
                           self.port,
                           NULL,
                           0)) {
        return NO;
    }

    // ... work with the DB

    mysql_close(&connection);

    return YES;
}
```

Works like a charm.

I have no idea why on my former attempts I got an error about the dylib; I never used it (only the static library).

The code signing issue may have been just a bug or one-time quirk in Xcode.